# How do I troubleshoot mysql and php?

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, mysql, php

PHP works, mysql works, but when I call mysql_connect, nothing happens.
What can I do?

Comment: ... You can tell us what error you're getting...

Comment: I'm not getting an error; I have to scripts, one simple form, index.php and another file, action.php. The action.php file is supposed to open a connection and insert the data from the form into a table.

Comment: Is this something you developed?  It almost sounds like it may belong on stackoverflow.  Have you examined the output of `mysql_error()`?

Comment: @Zoredache: mysql_error doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you need to enable error reporting in your php.ini file.  Or you can set this just within your script by adding these two lines:

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

That way you can see some error messages, and go from there.

Comment: Not necessarily. Let's see what the specific error is first.

Comment: I now have a script that reads
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);

  $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'website');
  if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
  }
?>

But still no error message

Comment: Scratch that, now, after a long time i get several warnings and one fatal error message: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\home\www\index.php on line 5

Comment: I reinstalled mysql this time with version 5.5 instead of 5.1. Thanks for the tip with the error reporting!